# SQL query where based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there an SQL query that change condition based on value of other column?

I want to perform a query that does the following

```
select colA,colB, colC
from TABLED
where colA > 10
  and (if colC == A then colB = 'C' else colB = 'B')
```

If that even makes sense, if `colC == A` we would have

```
select colA, colB, colC
from TABLED
where colA > 10 and colB = 'C'
```

otherwise we would have

```
select colA,colB,colC
from TABLED
where colA > 10 and colB = 'B'
```

Comment: You mean `WHERE (C = 'A' AND B = 'C') OR (C != 'A' AND B = 'B')`? This seems like you just need to determine your Boolean logic.

Comment: I guess `colC == 'A'` instead of `colC == A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express this using conditional logic.  No `case` is required:

```
select colA, colB, colC
from TABLED
where colA > 10 and
      ( (colC = A and colB = 'C') or
        (colC <> A and colB = 'B')
      );
```

This does not take into account that `colC` might be `NULL`.  That is easy to incorporate into the query, if it needs to.

Comment: I must have been thinking rocket science. :)